# How to set 1/0 as value to boolean type variables in java

Tags: java

actually i have a boolen variable 'boolean status' if it will return true i need to store 1 into db or else 0 would be stored how to change int value to boolean in java please help me..

boolean status=1;
customerTl.setStatus();

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean status = true;
    int numberToStore = status?1:0;
    System.out.println(numberToStore);
}
```

And just store numberToStore in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have a variable that will hold the 1 or 0 that you want to put in the database. You can set it simply by doing something like this:

```
boolean status = 0
int dbval = status ? 1 : 0;
```

This is equivalent to

```
boolean status = 0
int dbval = 0;
if (status) {
    dbval = 1;
} else {
    dbval = 0;
}
```

Hope this helped :)

Answer (score -1):

Don't think you have to change int to boolean here.

```
if(status){#insert 1 into db}
else{#insert 0 into db}
```

If else should understand 1 and 0 without you having to change int to boolean.